# I can't figure out how to get div with image to obey the height constrains of the parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to get the image to fit in my div that has dynamic height.
The height of the text caption is static as shown, but I can't figure out how to fit the image inside there.

A solution should not use percentages to specify the heights of the divs (e.g, 10% and 90%)

Also, as noted in the snippet, I need the full image contents. No `overflow: hidden;`

```js
  
const {useState} = React;

const App = ({}) => {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(100);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
      <div>
      <input onChange={e=>setHeight(e.target.value)} value={height}/>
      <div style={{ height: height + "px", border: "1px solid red" }}>
        <div>[TEXT CAPTION] Scale image to fit within the border. (<b>not</b> <code>overflow:hidden;</code>)</div>
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/bLrJmN3/3.png" />
        </div>
      </div>       
    </div>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 20px;
  height: 100px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

img {
  object-fit: contain;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: In React, the component needs to return only one root element.

Answer (score 0):

I read your question so In my opinion you want that your image autofit in div like parent div If you want your image is autofitted in div or grid the use this property `object-fit: cover;`

here is the code which i have tried and its working fine now

```
.grid-container > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

if you have any issues please describe little bit so its easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Just resize your height offset by the static size of the caption.
Suppose the caption is `10px`, then you do:

```
img {
 max-height: calc(100% - 10px);
 height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem you can just add a second argument to the `grid-template-rows` calculating the height of the second row `calc(100% - 20px)`

```js
  
const {useState} = React;

const App = ({}) => {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(100);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
      <div>
      <input onChange={e=>setHeight(e.target.value)} value={height}/>
      <div className="grid-container" style={{ height: height + "px" }}>
        <div>[TEXT CAPTION] Scale image to fit within the border. (<b>not</b> <code>overflow:hidden;</code>)</div>
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/bLrJmN3/3.png" />
        </div>
      </div>       
    </div>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 20px calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.grid-container > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

img {
  object-fit: contain;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```